# Getting old value in dropbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

How do i get `value="{{ old('gender') }}"` with dropdown?

I have name field:

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
```

which gives the old value if the form is rejected due to invalid validations: But How can i get what user selected before validation in dropdown box? `value="{{ old('name') }}"` is not working.

```
<label>Region:</label>
<select  name="region" id="region" value="{{ old('region') }}"  class="form-control" required>
     <option value="" disabled selected>--Select a Region--</option>
     @foreach($region as $reg)
          <option value="{{$reg->id}}">{{$reg->region_name}}</option>
     @endforeach       
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value on every option of your dropdown and add the `selected` attribute if it is a match.

Like so:

```
<select name="region" id="region" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="" disabled {{ empty(old('region')) ? 'selected' : '' }}>--Select a Region--</option>
    @foreach($region as $reg)
        <option value="{{$reg->id}}" {{ old('region') == $reg->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{$reg->region_name}}
        </option>
    @endforeach       
</select>
```